# my media query text is not being responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

Can I please get some assistance. my media query is not responding properly and I cant figure out whats wrong. My main problem is with the search title, the search input and the search results. I have tried adjusting the properties but I cant seem to get them to respond properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="some content">
    <title></title>
<style>



  *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
      }

  body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
   
  }
  

  /* Styles for the search bar container */
  .search-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('https://mgecustomprints.s3.amazonaws.com/Brown+Wood+Minimalist+Profile+LinkedIn+Banner+(3).png');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;

}




  .search-title {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #7c36ff;
    font-family: Canva Sans,Noto Sans Variable,Noto Sans,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 WHITE, 2px -2px 0 WHITE, -2px 2px 0 WHITE, 2px 2px 0 WHITE;
  }

  /* Styles for the search bar */
  .search-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #7c36ff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  .search-input {
    width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:#7c36ff;
  }

  /* Styles for the search results dropdown */
  .search-results {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%; /* Position the dropdown vertically in the middle */
    left: 50%; /* Position the dropdown horizontally in the middle */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Center the dropdown */
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 635px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
    max-height: 200px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
    overflow-y: auto; /* Add vertical scrollbar if needed */
     }

  .search-results.show {
    display: block;
  }

  .search-result {
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }

  .search-result a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
  }
 

.card-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  
}

.card {
  flex: 1;
   width: 300px;
   height: 500px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
  /* Remove margin property */
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: #7C36FF;
}

.card img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  
}


/* Random dummy image URLs */
.card:nth-child(1) img {
  content: url("https://mgecustomprints.s3.amazonaws.com/apparel.png");
  WIDTH: 500PX;
}

.card:nth-child(2) img {
  content: url("https://mgecustomprints.s3.amazonaws.com/request.png");
  WIDTH: 500PX;

}
.card:nth-child(3) img {
  content: url("https://mgecustomprints.s3.amazonaws.com/PACKAGED.png");
  WIDTH: 500PX;

}

.card:nth-child(4) img {
  content: url("https://mgecustomprints.s3.amazonaws.com/3P0B8216MARRICO+3.jpg");
  WIDTH: 500PX;

}



.card h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  color:WHITE;
}

.card p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: WHITE;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
</style><style>
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Styles for screens with a maximum width of 768px */
  .search-container {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .search-title {
                font-size: 30px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            .search-bar {
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: flex-start;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .search-input {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 600px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            .search-results {
                top: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 600px;
                height: 200px;
                overflow-y: auto;
            }

  .card-section {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
  }

  .card {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }

  .card img {
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}

</style>
```

I adjusted the values

Comment: Can you add more details about what is the problem ? what is your desired output?

Comment: My goal is for the text and input box centered on the image. The image is not risizing to the full screen width and the text is not shrinking to fit the image. The search box is also not lining up properly centered.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this seems like an obvious thing you've already tried, but have you tried adding `!important;` on the end of your media query rules just to rule out some things? Assuming your issue is that the rules under 768px just aren't showing in the inspector at all or are just over ruled?